# pointers and .net pointers

Tags: .net, null, nullptr

I heard that NULL is equivalent to .net nullptr and that 0 is not equivalent to .net nullptr.  why?  I thought that NULL is a macro equal to 0 ?

Comment: @Cody, there is.  Nullptr is a keyword in the C++/CLI language, around long before C++0x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends on if you're talking about unmanaged pointers or managed handles. Regarding pointers, a quote from the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex65770%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):
*The following sample shows that nullptr and zero can be used interchangeably on native 
pointers.*

However, if you're talking about a managed handle, then you can't use 0 as described in this quote from the same page:
*You cannot initialize a handle to zero; only nullptr can be used. Assignment of constant 0 to an object handle produces a boxed Int32 and a cast to Object^.*

Comment: So, there is no difference between NULL and 0 ?

Comment: @lital: Assuming that you're talking about C++, no.